# Error While opening ARFF file in WEKA

Tags: weka, arff

I had an excel sheet i converted it to ARFF file using online facility, but when i tried to open it in the 3.8 version of WEKA software it is showing me this error--

[image]

I have attached the image of the dialog box which is popping. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is difficult to help not knowing what your data looks like.  However, it likely departs from the expected format at line 1.  The link below details the format arff files should follow. http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B51xD24b2uu-Um9jaWY4akprMWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the link of the csv file if possible please convert and give it to me

Answer (score 0):

You can just open the CSV file with Weka explorer and save it as arff you really need it in that format.

EDIT:

Your problem is not the file format. It seems that all of your values are numeric. J48 is a classification algorithm and therefore Weka won't let you use it on numeric data.

Which column in the data is the target?
IF you want to use classification algorithm, you need to do one of the following: use a numeric-to-nominal filter on the target feature,  use an arff file where you specify that the target column is nominal or rename the values of the column to non-numeric values. Here is a link to an arff file where the last column (race) is defined as nominal: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7b0iysQV1SEcjJJUE1lc19fR2c

Comment: I tried as you said but for that file i cannot apply the J48 tree. The J48 icon is disabled. But it is enabled for all the rest of the dataset which came with the WEKA software. I am not getting where is actually the problem. If it is possible for you https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B51xD24b2uu-Um9jaWY4akprMWM/view?usp=sharing  this is the link of the file u can convert it and give to me

Comment: Your problem is not the file format. It seems that all of your values are numeric. Which column in the data is the target?

Comment: the target is 3rd and the 4th column (can L) and (Can R). Please can you help me out with this. Yes all the values are numerical. And the values which are not know are denoted by ? question mark. Please help me out.